# He had a child or his child was born?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Is it ok to say, **'And then he had a child'**, meaning that his child was born?

Suppose I'm telling a story about a man, and the person I'm telling the story to doesn't know that the man has a child.

Comment: Because ***to have a child*** is usually understood to mean ***give birth to a child***, your phrasing isn't "ideal". Note [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=He+had+a+child%2CShe+had+a+child&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHe%20had%20a%20child%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CShe%20had%20a%20child%3B%2Cc0) showing that ***He** had a child* has always been far less common than ***She** had a child*, (Despite the obvious fact that men become parents just as often as women do! :)

Comment: Thank you, @FumbleFingers So what should I say instead?

Comment: As @randomhead suggests, *He became a father / parent* gets you out of trouble. That's ***if*** you're sure you only want to announce that "bare fact" in your narrative context. It would often be more natural to introduce the woman who bore his child into the narrative at that point - *not* doing this might tend to imply that she's unimportant, which may or may not be the message you want to give out.

Comment: @FumbleFingers thank you. Does it mean that if I'm telling a story about a man, I have to bring up his wife to mention that he became a father, even if I haven't mentioned her before, and she's not relevant in the story? Should I say, 'And then his wife had a child'?

Comment: That's a cultural issue. If it's irrelevant to your narrative (and to the culture of your target readership) who *bore* the child, by all means don't bring it up. But certainly many people in most *Anglophone* cultures would be likely to notice the "omission", and think it was a bit "male-centric".

Comment: It's interesting. Thank you, @FumbleFingers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The act of "**having** a child" most literally means that the person has a uterus, and there is a a child in that uterus, and the child is in the process of transitioning from the uterus to the outside world (the process of delivery/childbirth). So when you say someone "**had** a child" you mean there was a baby inside them and then it was outside of them.

But it can also refer more metaphorically to the act of someone *obtaining* a child when they did not have a child before. So in this sense it can refer to a man or a woman *becoming a parent*. You can say that a man "had a child" and it will be understood by any English speaker that you mean the man's partner delivered their child, or even that the man adopted a child. It is not incorrect at all.

Comment: thank you! So does it mean it's idiomatic, and you often hear it?

Comment: @i_yre_b yes, it is very common to hear someone say "He had a child" meaning "He became a father."